# How to filter crystal report in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, filtering

[image]

When I select values from drop down then click on show button it should show the crystal report for that selection.

Comment: Have you created parameters in your .rpt?

Comment: I have to create .rpt after selecting options from drop down.

Comment: Ihsanullah - What code are you using to load the combo boxes up at the top of your form?  Others may be able to offer more help if they could see some of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are filtering programatically, you can type

```
crystalreportViewr1.selectionformula="{Report.Fieldname}='"+filterdata+"'";
```

This is for filter the `string` data type.
For `int` data type to be  filtered,

```
crystalreportViewr1.selectionformula="{Report.Fieldname}="+filterdata;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string myQuery = "{Report.FieldName} < '1000'";

crystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = myQuery;
```

Comment: Hi, I am having a bit of challenge with passing parameters to crystal report from c#. In the above code, does Report mean the full name of the report file or the database table name.

Comment: @Kunbi I had the same issue, Report refers to the table name as it is written in report. For example if the table name is `table`, in Crystal Reports, the name may be `table1`